# How to get the text of a hyperlink field inside a grid view in ASP .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

In my case my grid view can contain normal text or a hyperlink . I want to get the value of those fields. So far I have tried

```
        DataTable detailTable = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < gvTransactionDetails.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            detailTable.Columns.Add(gvTransactionDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text.ToString());
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvTransactionDetails.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = detailTable.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < gvTransactionDetails.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                Control hyperLink = gvrow.Cells[j].Controls[0] as LiteralControl;

                if (hyperLink != null)
                {
                    dr[j] = ((LiteralControl)gvrow.Cells[j].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    dr[j] = gvrow.Cells[j].Text.ToString();
                }
            }

            detailTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

The problem I am facing is as the first cell in each and every row is a hyperlink and rest all other cells only contain text values, after the first iteration of the foreach loop only I am getting "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index" exception.

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code as well for the GridView ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead in `RowDataBound` event of gridview like this:-

```
protected void gvTransactionDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lnkId= (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkId");
        if (lnkId!= null)
        {
            detailTable.Rows.Add(lnkId.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

You can attach this event like this to your gridview:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTransactionDetails" runat="server" 
              OnRowDataBound="gvTransactionDetails_RowDataBound">
```

Also, as a side note from your posted code, `.Text.ToString();` the `Text` property anyways returns a String so no need to convert it using `ToString`.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the answer? Did this worked for you?